How to show Sharepoint list calculated column in combo box?
In my Canvas app, I have a combo box that binds to a Sharepoint list calculated column calculatedColA.
Sharepoint list myList calculatedColA = TEXT([DateCol],"yyyymmd")&" "&[ColB]
When I run it, it doesn't show list of values for calculatedColA.
How can I show myList calculatedColA values in the combo box?
Thank you

Check that the calculated column is set up correctly in SharePoint and that the app has the necessary permissions to access the data.
